# Pearson correlation with overlapping data

Tags: time-series, correlation

I have a financial time series and I want to calculate correlation between past and future returns. First I select look back and holding periods, say *l* and *h* respectively. Then I calculate past returns, which is current value divided by the value *l* points ago and future returns which is the value *h* points ahead divided by the current value. And then I calculate Pearson correlation.

The problem is these returns obviously overlap. I found some solutions for linear regression, but not really for correlation. One suggestion is to calculate *n = min(l, h)* and pick every n-th point. This eliminates some overlapping, but not all of it. Another idea would be to calculate *n = max(l, h)*, which eliminates overlapping, but also leaves me with very little points for long periods. Some variations are e.g. selecting every h-th point. Every method produces different results.

Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are complaining that your timeseries is only observed
at discretized points, perhaps weekly.
Yet the way you've formulated the problem implicitly
makes the very strong assumption that prices are
drawn from a smoothly differentiable manifold.

So impute intermediate points, turning the observed timeseries
into a continuous function.

> select look back and holding periods

Prefer: "select look back and holding intervals".

That is, rather than looking back 3 rows in a spreadsheet,
you can instead look back 21 × 86_400 == 1_814_400 seconds.
And plug that into your linear interpolation imputer.
Or use splines.
Or a moving average that is windowed, or is exponentially smoothed,
whatever.

Comment: This is not a problem, I do actually have more precise data. Let's say, hypothetically, I used daily points and found correlation for intervals -2, +2 and now I do the same for hourly points with intervals -48, +48. If I select the same number of points from the whole dataset as I did with daily points, the result would be the same, because returns since 48h and 2d ago are the same number. If I take all the points from the hourly dataset, intuitively, I created more overlaps between adjacent points, because now I have 47 points overlapping (47h) and before I had 1 point overlapping (1d=24h).

Comment: I disagree with the “more [47] overlaps” and with the “two datasets” remarks. That is, I claim that after interpolation you have a single Continuous dataset, smoothly differentiable, to operate on.

Comment: Let's say I took the raw data (all transactions, without any aggregation) and I have my "single Continuous dataset, smoothly differentiable". How this eliminates the problem of overlapping periods?

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code you're running, please. We could examine a step-function investment with a closing price up through Jan. 3rd of 110, and from Jan. 4th onward it has a constant closing price of 120.